# купюроприемник и javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.
Я хочу через javascript работать с купюроприемниками.
Как мне реализовать получение данных через js и полноценно использовать все функции купюроприемника(calbakc) и тд.

В целом и идея реализовать все это на веб-приложение.

Comment: JavaScript является встраиваемым языком, который общается с внешним миром только через оболочку. Поэтому тут вопрос в том, какие средства предоставляет оболочка и какие варианты взаимодействия реализует купюромприемник. В случае с браузерами, они ему предоставляют возможность пересылать сообщения в форматах HTTP, тогда тут вариант только Ajax HTTP запросы, при условии, что у купюроприемника есть соответствующий API.

Comment: @AlexKrass а какой язык напрямую с купюроприемником сможет общаться? Все так или иначе оболочку какую-то используют (в виде API операционки или другой среды исполнения).

Comment: Погуглите по названию протокола. Вероятно уже есть открытые библиотеки, например для ccnet: https://github.com/soulman-is-good/ccnet

Answer (score -3):

Добрый день! Именно из js прямо на прямую реализовать протокол вряд ли получится. Т.к. там специфика устройств заключается как правило в том - что работают они через com/usb порт и работают по своим не совсем простым протоколам. Т.е. из js это просто физически крайне сложно сделать, да и к тому же не просто реализовать протокол

Как вариант это сделать через какое то промежуточное приложение, допустим на java, которое будет реализовывать протокол устройства и уже взаимодействовать с js. Наверное это самый простой и рациональный вариант

Comment: Здравствуйте. На этом сайте не принято ни предлагать услуги, ни искать исполнителей задачи. Формат сайта предполагает только открытые вопросы и ответы, доступные всем читателям.

Comment: @denis: Если вы хотите разместить информацию о том, где вас найти, лучшее место для этого — ваш профиль. Ссылки на себя в ответах будут скорее всего расценены как спам.

Comment: Ок, понял, контактную  информацию оставлять не буду, спасибо что поправили